# How do send sketch updates to devices without the editor?

Tags: uploading, firmware

I'd like to update the sketch of a device that a friend out of state is testing. I could have them install the full editor and send the source code but I'd rather not require them to do something so technical.

Is there a way to compile the firmware binary and push that out to a device over the COM port more directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, yes.

The compile routine creates a .hex file in a temporary directory that contains the flash image for the device. One can use AVRDUDE to upload this .hex file to the Arduino from the command line. It is simply a matter of getting the command arguments correct in order to tell it where and how to upload the image. Enabling verbose output in the IDE will tell you both exactly where the .hex file is located and what arguments are required for the board selected.

Comment: As a side note, latest openwrt version for the yun bundles reflash through http upload: you enter yun's webpanel, select the .hex to upload and click